# video only play in Internet Explorer not in other browser

Tags: asp.net, firefox, video

[image: Video in IE]

![In other broeser][2]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSDJB.png    code is  `<object classid="clsid:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" width="480" height="360"
        codebase="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/">
        <param name="Filename" value="hilo_data_final.wmv" />
        <param name="AutoStart" value="true" />
        <param name="ShowControls" value="true" />
        <param name="BufferingTime" value="2" />
        <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true" />
        <param name="AutoSize" value="true" />
        <param name="InvokeURLs" value="false" />
        <embed src="hilo_data_final.wmv" type="application/x-mplayer2"
            autostart="1" enabled="1" showstatusbar="1" showdisplay="1" showcontrols="1"
            pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=6,0,0,0"
            width="480" height="360"></embed>`

So what will be problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here you try to use the Windows Media Player to play the video. This is play only on IE and only on computers with windows and media player installed.

Is better to use some flash-base video player (like YouTube do) and then you have more computers and browser that be able to see it.

One suggestion is the flowplayer that I have test it and is very good.

http://flowplayer.org/